# Does Apple keep track of iOS app opening?

Tags: ios, applications

We would like to know if Apple keeps track of iOS App opening by users.

For example, Facebook keeps track of Facebook app opening to collect data of Facebook Insight.

Does Apple keep track of user behaviours like iOS app opening by users? Thanks.

Comment: No. Apple does not do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this using Apple’s built-in “Music” app on an iPhone 4 running iOS 5.1, using `ngrep` and `tcpdump` to monitor network activity. No connections to Apple servers are being made when opening an app on any iOS device.

As you mentioned, individual apps (e.g. Facebook) may keep track of data like this by pinging a server every time you open their app — but Apple does not do anything like this globally.

Comment: They'd be roasted by privacy advocated real quick if they did.